# Using Oracle client 32 bit on Win 10 64 bit

Tags: oracle

I am using Windows 10 64 bit and Oracle client 32 bit (It's my company requirement). But when I open some existed program, it display a dialog with error:

> Attempt to load oracle client libraries threw badimageformatexception.
>   This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit
>   Oracle client components installed

I had fixed by add Enviroment variables but it's not working. I am searching around Google, but the solution almost about fix on Visual Studio when developing application.

These program is existed, not run from Visual Studio.

How should I do to make application which using Oracle client 32 bit on OS 64 bit?

Comment: Perhaps telling us which program gives the error would help. Maybe it has a flag to run in 32-bit mode, oe a 32-bit version you can install. Why can't you install the 64-bit Oracle client?

Comment: @AlexPoole: It's a program of my company, not a public program. As I said, 32-bit Oracle client is my company requirement.

Comment: If your company requires you to use its own 64-bit program and also requires you to only have a 32-bit Oracle client then you need to talk to whoever is making or imposing those conflicting requirements.

Comment: Yes, I will check again. Because this problem only occured with existed program

Answer (score 1):

A 32 bit application requires also a 32 bit Oracle Client. A 64 bit application (resp. "AnyCPU" on windows 64 bit) requires a 64 bit Oracle Client.

Unless you use the ODP.NET Managed Driver (see [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html)) there is not way to get rid of it. One solution is to install both, 32 bit and 64 bit Oracle Client, follow this instruction: [BadImageFormatException. This will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100)